# Seaborn showing wrong y-axis values

Tags: python, seaborn

The dataframe I created is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

date = pd.date_range('2003-01-01', '2022-11-01', freq='MS').strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()
mom = [np.nan] + list(np.repeat([0.01], 238))
cpi = [100] + list(np.repeat([np.nan], 238))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date, mom, cpi)), columns=['date','mom','cpi'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

for i in range(1,len(df),1):
    df['cpi'][i] = df['cpi'][(i-1)] * (1 + df['mom'][i])

df['yoy'] = df['cpi'].pct_change(periods=12)
```

[image]

Y-axis values not displaying correctly as can be seen below.

```
sns.lineplot(
    x = 'date',
    y = 'yoy',
    data = df
)
```

[image]

I think the percentage changes I calculated for the yoy column are the cause of the issue. Because there are no issues if I manually fill in the yoy column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You see the differences from the 12th digit after the decimal point onwards only as there is no other difference elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib to set the axis scaling, as the difference is really subtle in your data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([df.yoy.min(numeric_only=True), df.yoy.max(numeric_only=True)])

sns.lineplot(
    x = 'date',
    y = 'yoy',
    data = df,
    ax = ax
)
```

With this the result should be more of a stepping function.

[image: Image of plot with scaled y axis]

You can use something like the max difference to the mean times 1.01 to set the limits a little better, but this is the idea. You can set the axis ticks using `ax.set_yticks(ticks=<list of ticks>)` [(documentation).](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html)